# Why do most examples of CSRF use roundabout ways of executing an API call instead of just using pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies, csrf, web

When I see examples of CSRF attacks, it is almost always explained with someone entering some external API url in an `<img>` tag, e.g. `<img src="bank.com/transfer?amount=10000?recipient=badguy">`. Or it involves a form which when submitted executes a POST request to bank.com.

My question is why not just include the API call in a `<script>` tag? For example,

```
<html>
    ...
    <script>
        fetch("bank.com/transfer?amount=10000?recipient=badguy", method: "POST");
    </script>
</html>
```

Wouldn't this have the same effect, or perhaps even greater effect since the user wouldn't have to manually submit a form?

Comment: not exactly the same effect, as it would trigger the browser to send pre-flight check for CORS.  (the popularity of creating CSRF attacks in this way is probably what led the browsers to include cross-origin restrictions...)

Comment: Thank you. This has helped me understand better. IIUC, some "simple" requests are not subject to the same origin policy. For example, embedding images like `<img src="othersite.com/image.jpg">`. This was done for backwards compatibility reasons. Similarly "POST" requests originating from a `<form>` are considered "simple" requests and thus do not require CORS preflight. Not sure why this is allowed, maybe also for backwards compatibility? Meanwhile requests from AJAX or fetch are not considered "simple" and thus trigger a preflight.

Comment: @pcalkins That is false. Literally any request that _can_ be sent via an HTML form will _NOT_ trigger a CORS preflight; that's the easiest way to distinguish CORS requests that would from those ("simple" requests) that would not.

Comment: according to this page any JS request must be same-origin unless server allows CORS... which would be checked via pre-flight, no?: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: @pcalkins A useful experiment: create a cookie on `https://example.com` and then run `fetch('//example.com', {mode: 'no-cors', credentials: 'include'})`. The request will not participate in the CORS protocol (but will, incidentally, be authenticated).

Comment: I tried this from cross-origin and the cookies were not sent.  Not exactly sure why that was, though.  (cookies were default values... maybe same-site 'lax' prevented?)  (Negotiate was failing, too so not sure if that's a good test case.)  It seems like Chrome was not sending credentials cross-origin.

Comment: good to know, though... I suppose if cookies were set as same-site: none, then no pre-flight happens in no-cors mode and cookies would be sent.

Answer (score 0):

A form can also be submitted automatically by JavaScript, without the user clicking the button. In my experience, a HTML page with a form (without JavaScript) is usually given as evidence, with the implication that it can also be submitted automatically. Omitting the autosubmit code makes it easier to test and reproduce the CSRF.

The [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is a fairly recent development (~2016), and the method to do requests from JavaScript before that ([XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)) did not really have a straightforward API.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, a lot of it is probably just inertia. CSRF has existed longer than CORS has; script-initiated requests used to only be able to target the current origin. Those days are long past now, but people tend to repeat examples from how they learned, or that they've used before. That's especially true with topics where people just don't understand what they're talking about, which CORS is absolutely *rife* with.

Another possible reason is that some people rely on the `Origin` request header to detect CSRF. This is unwise for two reasons: browsers don't always send the `Origin` header on cross-site requests, even POST ones (this may be standard now, but for a long time it was only required on POST requests), and attacker can cause the `Origin` header value to be `null`, which can also happen for valid requests unless the site is careful to ensure valid requests would not. Anyhow, modern browsers will probably always set `Origin` for POST requests, whether from HTML forms or scripts, but it wasn't always so and thus you could bypass poorly-implemented CSRF protection on some sites that way.

Finally, unlike script-initiated requests, form submissions are *navigation* requests. This isn't always desirable for an attacker - usually they want the attack to be invisible to the user, and thus a navigation request is undesirable unless it's in an invisible iframe or something - but for a *proof of concept or demonstration* it's very handy (as it allows easily seeing the response and in general the result), and people often desire that visibility when either teaching somebody about CSRF, or providing proof of a vulnerability.